# Some but not all matches disappearing, not loaded from Game Center

Tags: game-center, gamekit, gkturnbasedmatch

I have an iOS turn-based match app using GameKit. Recently, I've had some matches on Game Center disappear. It's about one in six with no rhyme or reason. GKTurnBasedMatch.loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler fetches Game Center matches successfully, but a few of my ongoing or old matches are no longer there. However, when I go to the separate Game Center app and look at my Turns, I can see the missing matches there -- my app just can't access them. 
the weird thing is that it is only a fraction of the total that have disappeared. Not sure if it matters, but when this happened I had more than 30 total matches but fewer than 30 active matches. The issue occurs both in sandbox and production versions. Has anyone else seen this issue?

Comment: These missing matches reappeared 3 days later. I did nothing to change my code during that time.

Answer (score 0):

According to this wwdc session http://asciiwwdc.com/2013/sessions/506 a game can have up to 30 matches. The speaker doesn't describe what happens if you try to create a 31st. It appears, based on your experience, that any extras are subject to disappearing.

I have never seen this limit mentioned in any of the game center docs, just in the wwdc videos.

Comment: It won't let you create a new match if you have 30 matches already. However, it has at least previously allowed you to have more than 30 matches if someone else creates the new matches and invites you. In my case, active matches just disappeared. You would think that if anything, old, completed matches would be deleted first when I am over the limit.

Comment: I would think that if it can block me from creating more than 30, that it could also block me from accepting more than 30 invites. And like you say, I would have expected it to delete the oldest, completed matches first. I hadn't built in any protections around 30 matches; guess I'll have to go look at that now, too. :(